# How do I handle strange characters in Arduino code

Tags: c++, character-encoding, arduino

I have a GPS unit connected to my Arduino which outputs a lot of data which I would like to filter.

Here is a snippet of the output:

> $ÇÐÇÇÁ,175341.458,3355.7870,Ó,01852.4251,Å,1,03,5.5,-32.8,Í,32.8,Í,,0000*57
>   $ÇÐÇÓA,Á,2,31,32,20,,,,,,,,,,5.6,5.5,1.0*30
>   $ÇÐÒÍÃ,175341.458,Á,3355.7870,Ó,01852.4251,Å,0.17,223.13,060812,,*1C
>   $ÇÐGÇÁ,175342.458,3355.7871,Ó,01852.4251,Å,1,03,5.5,-32.8,Í,32.8,Í,,0000*55
>   $GÐÇÓÁ,Á,2,31,32,20,,,,,,,,,,5.5,5.5,1.0*33
>   $ÇÐÒÍC,175342.458,Á,3355.7871,Ó,01852.4251,Å,0.22,4.85,060812,,*10
>   $ÇÐÇÇÁ,175343.458,3355.7872,S,01852.4251,Å,1,03,5.5,-32.8,Í,32.8,Í,,0000*57

This is read in with the following method:

```
char GPSread()
{
  byte val = 0;
  while (digitalRead(GPSrx));
  //wait for start bit
  if (digitalRead(GPSrx) == LOW)
  {
    delayMicroseconds(halfBit4800Delay);
    for (int offset = 0; offset < 8; offset++)
    {
        delayMicroseconds(bit4800Delay);
        val |= digitalRead(GPSrx) << offset;
    }
    //wait for stop bit + extra
    delayMicroseconds(bit4800Delay);
    delayMicroseconds(bit4800Delay);
    return val;
  }
}
```

**My goal**

I am trying to filter this data to obtain only the lines starting with `$ÇÐÇÇÁ` to use the data within this line. I am new to working with strings as a `char[]`.

**My attempt**

So what I'm currently trying is to read these values into a `char[]` and then when I get a match to `$ÇÐÇÇÁ` I know I've got this line. But I found this which got me stuck:

```
char dataformat [12] = "$ÇÐÇÇÁ";
Serial.println(dataformat [0]);
Serial.println(dataformat [1]);
Serial.println(dataformat [2]);
Serial.println(dataformat [3]);
Serial.println(dataformat [4]);
Serial.println(dataformat [5]);
```

outputs as

> $
>   Ã
>
> Ã
>
> Ã

Which is not the same as the characters I inserted on init of `dataformat[]`. I know this is an encoding thing but have no idea how to go about it.

**The question**

How could I filter this data to obtain only the lines I want?

Comment: Try using `if (isAlphanum(mychar)) {...}` to filter characters, or `if (strncmp ("MYSTRING", myString", 5) == 0) {...}` to check for a specific five characters at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @paulsm4 but What would it help if I check to see if it is alphabetic number?